# extract value from array and create variable with it

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, attributes

Having this following array:

```
Array
(
    [new] => Array
        (
            [data-title] => Crear grupo
            [class] => test1, test2, test3
            [style] => float:left; border:1px solid red;
        )

    [trash] => Array
        (
            [class] => delete
        )

    [0] => edit
)
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to extract `data-title`'s, `class`'s, or any other sub array and convert it's value to a variable containing that value so I can access it anytime I want by just echoing it like so `echo $title`

The first part is easy, but I wonder if there would be any way of **automatically translate `[data-title] => Crear grupo` to `data-title="Crear grupo"`**

```
foreach($buttons as $button => $attribute) {

         $title = $attribute['data-title'];
         $classes = $attribute['class'];

         echo "<li data-title='$title' class='$classes'>"

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach ($buttons as $button => $attribute) {
    $str = "<li ";

    foreach ($attribute as $attr => $val) {
        $str .= $attr . '="' . $val . '" ';
    }
    $str .= ">";
}
```

Comment: that's what I was thinking at, but it seems a bit dirty... hmm, tnx any way Matt

Comment: @W0rldart no dirt in there - that just makes it more extensible.